# scratchでスプライトをドラッグしているときだけ別のスプライトを表示させたい

Tags: mit-scratch

ネコのスプライトをドラッグしたときだけ、煙のスプライトを表示させたいが、どこをクリックしている間でも煙が表示されてしまう。
ネコのスプライトをドラッグしたとき「だけ」の方法をどなたか教えていただきたいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

たしかにこのプログラムだと、一度ネコを押したらあとはどこを押しても煙が表示されてしまいます。この原因は、「ずっと」を使っていることです。煙のクローンを作る部分がずっと終わらないので、マウスが押されるたびに煙が表示されてしまいます。

そこで、ネコが押されたらその押している期間だけ煙のクローンを作って、そのまま終わるようにしてみます。こうするとマウスを押すのをやめるたびにこのプログラムが止まるので、たとえ他の場所を押しても反応しません。ネコを押したときだけ煙がクローンされて出てきます。

[image]